# simulation using for loop based on multiple conditions

Tags: r

I want to create a for loop which is able to handle multiple condition and keep result in a matrix named `mat`. for this purpose, I have a data frame named `df` and a sequence of numbers which I am used as `weight` named  `w`.

```
w<- seq(.01,.1, .009)
mat<- matrix(0,11,10)
df<- data.frame(year=c( 2000:2010), ph= c(12:22), ph_fit=c(14,15,18,16,20,15,17,23,11,19,26)
                ,b= c(-2,-1,3,-1.5,-4,5,5.5,-6,3.5,2.1,-5.4))
```

what I want is simulating `b` for each year based on value in `w` using this conditions:

if ph_fit > ph, the new estimate of `b (b_fit)` will be `b_fit= b* 1+(w)` (where b <0 ) and `b_fit=b* 1-w` (where b >0).

for next condition I have:

if ph_fit < ph, the new estimate of `b (b_fit)` will be `b_fit= b* 1+w` (where b > 0 ) and `b_fit=b* 1-w` (where b < 0).
this is an iterative process and repeat for each value in `w`.

by the code below, I have tried but got some error:

```
for (i in 1: 11) {
  if (df$ph_fit > df$ph & df$b < 0) {
    mat[, i] = df$b * 1 + w
  } else if (df$b > 0) {
    mat[, i] = df$b * 1 - w
  } else if (df$ph_fit < df$ph & df$b < 0) {
    mat[, i] = df$b * 1 - w
  } else if (df$b > 0) {
    mat[, i] = df$b * 1 + w
  }

}
```

my expected output for `b_fit` would be like this:

```
        `2000` `2001` `2002` `2003` `2004` `2005` `2006` `2007` `2008` `2009` `2010`
        <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 w1     -2.02  -1.01   2.97  -1.52  -4.04   5.05   5.56  -6.06   3.46   2.12  -5.45
 2 w2     -2.04  -1.02   2.94  -1.53  -4.08   5.10   5.60  -6.11   3.43   2.14  -5.50
 3 w3     -2.06  -1.03   2.92  -1.54  -4.11   5.14   5.65  -6.17   3.40   2.16  -5.55
 4 w4     -2.07  -1.04   2.89  -1.56  -4.15   5.18   5.70  -6.22   3.37   2.18  -5.60
 5 w5     -2.09  -1.05   2.86  -1.57  -4.18   5.23   5.75  -6.28   3.34   2.20  -5.65
 6 w6     -2.11  -1.06   2.84  -1.58  -4.22   5.28   5.80  -6.33   3.31   2.22  -5.70
 7 w7     -2.13  -1.06   2.81  -1.60  -4.26   5.32   5.85  -6.38   3.28   2.23  -5.75
 8 w8     -2.15  -1.07   2.78  -1.61  -4.29   5.36   5.90  -6.44   3.24   2.25  -5.79
 9 w9     -2.16  -1.08   2.75  -1.62  -4.33   5.41   5.95  -6.49   3.21   2.27  -5.84
10 w10    -2.18  -1.09   2.73  -1.64  -4.36   5.46   6.00  -6.55   3.18   2.29  -5.89
11 w11    -2.2   -1.1    2.7   -1.65  -4.4    5.5    6.05  -6.6    3.15   2.31  -5.94
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the main problem with your loop, is that you in each iteration use all "df", which mean that your "if" statements have multiple outputs. i.e. for the first "if" statement of the first iteration

"df$ph_fit > df$ph & df$b < 0" gives [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

So you need to subset your data, inside the loop, example below below. In addition, be aware of the dimensions of your matrix which ends up 11x11 (not 11x10).

```
w<- seq(.01,.1, .009)
mat<- matrix(0,11,11)
df<- data.frame(year=c( 2000:2010), ph= c(12:22), ph_fit=c(14,15,18,16,20,15,17,23,11,19,26)
                ,b= c(-2,-1,3,-1.5,-4,5,5.5,-6,3.5,2.1,-5.4))


for (i in 1:11){
  data <- df[i, ]
  if(data$ph_fit > data$ph & data$b < 0)
  { mat[,i] = data$b * 1+w}
  else if (data$b > 0 )
  {mat[,i] = data$b * 1-w}
  else if( data$ph_fit < data$ph & data$b < 0)
  {mat[,i]= data$b * 1-w}
  else if (data$b > 0)
  {mat[,i] = data$b * 1+w}
  
}
```

Comment: thank you Jost but why the output with your code is different with mine?

Comment: Hi, I did wonder that as well, I think what is missing to get your results are some brackets, like  "data$b * (1+w)"